# How to warn caller of a func in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-warnings, func

I am refactoring a large `iOS Swift` project gradually. Some function have to be renamed and I cannot rename directly because many other modules directly calling it. Instead, for the first phase release, I want to let the caller of a function know that please use this func instead of this func. Let me explain with an example,

```swift
func length() - > Int {
    //..... some logic
}
```

Expecting to refactor it in next version to,

```swift
func count() - > Int {
    //..... same logic
}
```

For the 1st phase I want to keep both `length()` and `count()` but let other developers be warned not to use existing one, i.e. length(). So I tried with,

```swift
func length() - > Int {
    #warning("Please use count() instead")
    //..... some logic
}
```

But the warning is thrown in the line but not to the caller. So, what are the best way to let caller be informed about wrong call?

Note: The example here is just a simplest form to understand the problem. Actual implementation is much broader in scope and module size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manage the availability of a method with `@available` keyword.

To **warn** the user:

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Please use count() instead")
func length() - > Int { }
```

To **force** the user:

```
@available(*, unavailable, message: "Please use count() instead")
func length() - > Int { }
```

To **suggest** the user to rename the function:

```
@available(*, renamed: "count()")
func length() - > Int { }
```

Also you can set the platform and the deprecation version if you need to (even without a message):

```
@available(iOS, deprecated:11.2)
func length() - > Int { }
```

Comment: It may be to worth to mention the `@available(*, renamed: "count()")` option as well, because that offers an inline rename feature in Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `available` keyword

You can use it in a couple of ways, if you want to show a warning to the developer then you should use `deprecated`, however if you want to force them then use `unavailable`

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "Please use count() instead")
func length() - > Int {
}
```

More information available at [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-available-to-deprecate-old-apis)